# Populating dropdownlists for mult-tenant applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database-design, localization, multi-tenant

I am building an mvc 3 application that will be multi-tenant, which means it will use the same basic data structure, but provide different data depending on the domain name used to access it.

A problem I am trying to solve is this.  How best do I populate a number of dropdown lists with selection choices based on the site being rendered.  To add another wrinkle, I will need to localize the strings as well.

An obvious choice is to simply create a table with columns for website id and language id, plus field id and string value.  This seems ok, but also seems to ignore possible mechanisms that are already in place for localization.  I feel like i'm recreating the wheel here.

As an example, site 1 might have a dropdownlist for Favorite Activities, and have ranges items that are geared toward musical interests.  Site 2 might have the same dropdown, but have items geared for sports intersts.

So my question is, how would you go about solving this problem?  Also, in a similar vein... If you have selection lists, say State codes, cities, etc.. would you tend to create seperate tables to populate this data (states table, cities table, etc..) or would you put all this information in a common table and have an ID to indicate which dropdown it was to be used for?   The former seems more normalized, but the latter seems more efficient (less code to write).

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with asp.net-mvc.  Multi-tenantcy is pretty language agnostic and what your asking is more of a data design question.

Comment: It has to do with asp.net-mvc because of the localization aspects, and what localization methods are provided by asp.net-mvc.  Further, it has to do with the ways in which drop-downlists are populated, which differs in MVC versus other frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thoughts about Common Lookup Tables. This guy is definitely against.

http://www.projectdmx.com/dbdesign/lookup.aspx

I have used it and believe that I have saved some time, or at least some keystrokes. Might be sorry later on.

Comment: He has some interesting comments.  I don't really agree with some of them, or rather I think they are overly theoretical.  However he does make some good points.  There is this divide in database design between purists and pragmatists.  Purists believe in highly normalized data, with natural keys.  In practice, the technology often makes that approach difficult.  Also, purists tend to think of data models as modeling real life, but some data models have to make concessions (for example, to be extensible or to deal with multi-tenant issues).

Comment: The link is no longer available, so the answer is not really valid.